# React router dom load component under the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working with a react app, I have a menu on top menu links are working great there is no problem with router but in my home page I add some buttons that do same job with menu but when I click buttons my pages are opening under the home page

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Menu from './components/Navi';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Candidates from './pages/Candidates';
import Employers from './pages/Employers';
import JobAdverts from './pages/JobAdverts';
import NoMatch from './pages/NoMatch';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (    
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Menu />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
            <Route path="/candidates" component={ Candidates }/>
            <Route path="/employers" component={ Employers }/>
            <Route path="/jobadverts" component={ JobAdverts }/>
            <Route component={ NoMatch }/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js**
When I add <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
my home page is not opening, it shows white page and refreshing icon gif

```
import React from 'react'
import Jumbotron from '../components/Jumbotron'
import Candidates from "../pages/Candidates";
import Employers from '../pages/Employers';
import JobAdverts from '../pages/JobAdverts';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from "react-router-dom"
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Jumbotron />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/candidates" component={ Candidates } />
          <Route path="/employers" component={ Employers } />
          <Route path="/jobadverts" component={ JobAdverts } />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**Jumbotron/index.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { Jumbo, Title, ButtonGroup } from './style'
import { Container, Button } from "react-bootstrap"
import {
  Link
} from "react-router-dom"

const Jumbotron = () => {
  return (
    <Jumbo>
      <div>
        <Title>
          <Container>
            <h1 className="text-center align-center fw-bold">Title</h1>
            <p className="text-center fw-light mt-5">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
          </Container>
        </Title>
        <ButtonGroup className="mt-5">
          <Link to="/candidates">
            <Button className="m-3" variant="light">Candidates</Button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/jobadverts">
            <Button className="m-3" variant="light">Job Adverts</Button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/employers">
            <Button className="m-3" variant="light">Employers</Button>
          </Link>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
    </Jumbo>
  )
}

export default Jumbotron
```

Comment: This is an expected behaviour . What you have is the nested routes . If you do not want it to get rendered inside your home page then you can remove the routes in your `Home.js`

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciated it worked!